# Insert Row from dropdown menu with data from other table

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 tables What i try is  in last div where is CategoryName to be a DrobDown list with Names that i've already insert...how to get this data? If something  about code is not  clear i will explain 
this is my Model:

```
public class Profits
{
 [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }    
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreation { get; set; }
    public ProfitCategories CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

}

this is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult DoInsertProf(Profits profits)
        {
            var Profit = new Profits
            {
                CategoryName = profits.CategoryName,
                Value = profits.Value,
              DateCreation = DateTime.Now,
                Description = profits.Description,
            };
            db.Profit.Add(profits);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Redirect("/SelectData/ReadProfit");
        }
```

and this is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoInsertProf","InsertProfit"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Profits</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>




         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName)
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really not clear and you code doesn't help...Are you trying to load a form with a DropDown populated or show some results after a save has been performed?

Comment: trying to load with a dropdown and data in dropdown are from here  in model :public ProfitCategories CategoryName { get; set; }

Comment: hmm ok then you should use DropDownList or DropDownListFor probably.  Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070762/mvc3-razor-html-dropdownlistfor)