# DropDownList in MVC 4 with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create a `DropDownList` on a razor view.

Would someone help me with this?

**Normal HTML5 code:**

```
<select id="dropdowntipo">
    <option value="Exemplo1">Exemplo1</option>
    <option value="Exemplo2">Exemplo2</option>
    <option value="Exemplo3">Exemplo3</option>
</select>
```

I tried this:

```
@{
    var listItems = new List<ListItem> { 
        new ListItem { Text = "Exemplo1", Value = "Exemplo1" }, 
        new ListItem { Text = "Exemplo2", Value = "Exemplo2" }, 
        new ListItem { Text = "Exemplo3", Value = "Exemplo3" } 
    };
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => 
    model.tipo, 
    new SelectList(listItems), 
    "-- Select Status --"
)
```

Comment: your `var listItems = ...` should be in your controller not your View.

Comment: this is MVC3 but it's the same syntax as MVC4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070762/mvc3-razor-html-dropdownlistfor

Comment: @Liam: It probably belongs in the view model, not in the controller.  The controller shouldn't have a dependency on `ListItem` as it's a UI-bound concept.  It shouldn't even _really_ be in the view model, just in the view.  The controller should build the view model, the view model should contain the data, the view should build UI elements (like `ListItem`) to that data.

Comment: also try [this one](http://lesson8.blogspot.com/2013/06/bind-dropdownlist-in-mvc4-razor.html)

Comment: What is the value of using Razor over native HTML; Is it performance or functionality? Since no data is being pulled from the controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate dropdownlist in asp.net MVC razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099258/how-to-generate-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc-razor)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382311/populating-a-razor-dropdownlist-from-a-listobject-in-mvc

Comment: Someone please tell me what the model.tipo property represents, in a generic sense.

Comment: On the last line - How do you know what model to call? Where does "tipo" come from?

Comment: user4234032 - model.tipo is the property on the model class that will store the selected value of the drop down list. In this example the value for the drop down list is a string so tipo will most likely be a string property. 

public string tipo {get; set; }

Answer (score 259, accepted):

```
@{
   List<SelectListItem> listItems= new List<SelectListItem>();
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
          Text = "Exemplo1",
          Value = "Exemplo1"
        });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Exemplo2",
            Value = "Exemplo2",
            Selected = true
        });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Exemplo3",
            Value = "Exemplo3"
        });
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.tipo, listItems, "-- Select Status --")
```

Comment: If you defined the List in controller, Then you need in View to cast it , like this:   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.model_year, ViewBag.Years as List<SelectListItem>, "-- Select Year --")

Comment: On the last line - How do you know what model to call? Where does "tipo" come from?

Comment: @Andre It's the name of model property. He read it from the question. The value binds to that field.

Comment: You have to be careful as none of the posted solutions perform any kind of server-side validation. Here's an elegant solution that performs both client-side and server-side validation to ensure valid data is posted to the model. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56185910/3960200

Comment: Ur showing a list that has no relevance ur not setting it anywhere please tidy up code

Answer (score 74):

```
@{var listItems = new List<ListItem>
    {
          new ListItem { Text = "Exemplo1", Value="Exemplo1" },
          new ListItem { Text = "Exemplo2", Value="Exemplo2" },
          new ListItem { Text = "Exemplo3", Value="Exemplo3" }
    };
    }
        @Html.DropDownList("Exemplo",new SelectList(listItems,"Value","Text"))
```

Comment: For this example to work I added this using above this code segment. @using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

Answer (score 44):

You can use this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Tipo, new List<SelectListItem>
    {
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Exemplo1", Value="Exemplo1"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Exemplo2", Value="Exemplo2"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Exemplo3", Value="Exemplo3"}
    })
```

Comment: What is "tipo"?

Comment: @Andre. Property Tipo on model. Look the first post.

Comment: thanks, I still have no idea where he got that from though

Comment: `Tipo` means `Type` in Spanish.

Comment: After 4 years, somebody finally answered that question.  Good.

Answer (score 22):

//ViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{

    public RegisterViewModel()
    {
        ActionsList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ActionsList { get; set; }

    public string StudentGrade { get; set; }

  }
```

//Enum Class:

```
public enum GradeTypes
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    G,
    H
}
```

//Controller Action

```
 public ActionResult Student()
    {
RegisterViewModel vm = new RegisterViewModel();
IEnumerable<GradeTypes> actionTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(GradeTypes))
                                             .Cast<GradeTypes>();
        vm.ActionsList = from action in actionTypes
                         select new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Text = action.ToString(),
                             Value = action.ToString()
                         };
        return View(vm);
    }
```

//view Action

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="hobies">Student Grade:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StudentGrade, Model.ActionsList, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is the easiest answer:

in your view only just add:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.tipo, new SelectList(new[]{"Exemplo1",
"Exemplo2", "Exemplo3"}))
```

**OR** 
in your controller add:

```
var exemploList= new SelectList(new[] { "Exemplo1:", "Exemplo2", "Exemplo3" });
        ViewBag.ExemploList = exemploList;
```

and your view just add:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.tipo, (SelectList)ViewBag.ExemploList )
```

I learned this with Jess Chadwick

Answer (score 10):

Believe me I have tried a lot of options to do that 
[and I have answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39062292/4251431)

but I always look for the best practice and the best way I know so far for both front-end and back-end developers is `for loop` (yes I'm not kidding)

Because when the front-end gives you the UI Pages with dummy data he also added  classes and some inline styles on specific select option so its `hard to deal` with using `HtmlHelper`

Take look at this :

```
<select class="input-lg" style="">
    <option value="0" style="color:#ccc !important;">
        Please select the membership name to be searched for
    </option>
    <option value="1">11</option>
    <option value="2">22</option>
    <option value="3">33</option>
    <option value="4">44</option>
</select>
```

this from the front-end developer so best solution is to use the for loop

fristly `create` or `get your list` of data from (...) in the Controller Action and put it in ViewModel, ViewBag or whatever

```
//This returns object that contain Items and TotalCount
ViewBag.MembershipList = await _membershipAppService.GetAllMemberships();
```

Secondly in the view do this simple for loop to populate the dropdownlist

```
<select class="input-lg" name="PrerequisiteMembershipId" id="PrerequisiteMembershipId">
    <option value="" style="color:#ccc !important;">
        Please select the membership name to be searched for
    </option>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.MembershipList.Items)
    {
        <option value="@item.Id" @(Model.PrerequisiteMembershipId == item.Id ? "selected" : "")>
            @item.Name
        </option>
    }
</select>
```

in this way you will not break UI Design, and its simple , easy and more readable

hope this help you even if you did not used razor

Comment: Thanks bro, Microsoft documentation says you can use asp-items="[yourListHere]" but I found when I tried that it didn't display anything at all. When I used a For Each loop it all displayed properly.

Answer (score 8):

Using an array would be a little more efficient than creating a list.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Tipo, new SelectListItem[]{
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Exemplo1", Value="Exemplo1"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Exemplo2", Value="Exemplo2"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Exemplo3", Value="Exemplo3"}})
```

Answer (score 8):

```
@{
List<SelectListItem> listItems= new List<SelectListItem>();
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
      Text = "One",
      Value = "1"
    });
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Two",
        Value = "2",
    });
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Three",
        Value = "3"
    });
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
{
   Text = "Four",
   Value = "4"
});
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
{
   Text = "Five",
   Value = "5"
});
}
@Html.DropDownList("DDlDemo",new SelectList(listItems,"Value","Text"))
```

Refer:- [Create drop down list in MVC 4 razor example](https://web.archive.org/web/20150709153249/jqueryasp.net/create-drop-down-list-in-mvc-4-razor-example)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using ASP.net 5 (MVC 6) or later then you can use the [new Tag Helpers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/853835/TagHelpers) for a very nice syntax:

```
<select asp-for="tipo">
    <option value="Exemplo1">Exemplo1</option>
    <option value="Exemplo2">Exemplo2</option>
    <option value="Exemplo3">Exemplo3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example where the items are dynamic? For a static list no point to use tag helpers. And make one of the options selected.

Comment: The point is that it's data bound. It automatically selects the option that the variable is set to and it sets the variable when the form is submitted. To make the items dynamic, just do a razor foreach.

Answer (score 4):

just use This

```
public ActionResult LoadCountries()
{
     List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
     li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
     li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "India", Value = "1" });
     li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Srilanka", Value = "2" });
     li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "China", Value = "3" });
     li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Austrila", Value = "4" });
     li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "5" });
     li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "UK", Value = "6" });
     ViewData["country"] = li;
     return View();
}
```

and in View use following.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Country", ViewData["country"] as List<SelectListItem>)
```

if you want to get data from Dataset and populate these data in a list box then use following code.

```
List<SelectListItem> li= new List<SelectListItem>();
for (int rows = 0; rows <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; rows++)
{
    li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rows][1].ToString(), Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rows][0].ToString() });
}
ViewData["FeedBack"] = li;
return View();
```

and in view write following code.

```
@Html.DropDownList("FeedBack", ViewData["FeedBack"] as List<SelectListItem>)
```

Answer (score 3):

This can also be done like

```
@model IEnumerable<ItemList>
```

```html
<select id="dropdowntipo">
    <option value="0">Select Item</option>
    
    @{
      foreach(var item in Model)
      {
        <option value= "@item.Value">@item.DisplayText</option>
      }
    }

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
List<tblstatu> status = new List<tblstatu>();
            status = psobj.getstatus();
            model.statuslist = status;
            model.statusid = status.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.StatusId.ToString(),
                Text = x.StatusName
            });


  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.status_id, Model.statusid, "Select", new { @class = "form-control input-xlarge required", @type = "text", @autocomplete = "off" })
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using **.NET Core MVC** who stumbled across this:

If your model has an enum for the property, you can simply put:

```
<select asp-for="MyEnum" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<MyEnum>()"/>
```

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#enum-binding

Hope this helps someone.