# MVC5 EF Return data to view

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have one table called `access` `linked with FK to user's table`, so, a user have a collection of accesses.

With this, my controller return a list with all accesses.

I want to create a dropdown with all users that are on user's table.

To to that i followed the 1st answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382311/populating-a-razor-dropdownlist-from-a-listobject-in-mvc) question.

I'll paste here the code of my controller that return a view do index:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string sortOrder)
{
    ViewBag.IDSortParm = sortOrder == "ID_asc" ? "ID_desc" : "ID_asc";
    ViewBag.EmailSortParm = sortOrder == "Email_asc" ? "Email_desc" : "Email_asc";
    ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
    ViewBag.NameSortParm = sortOrder == "Name_asc" ? "Name_desc" : "Name_asc";

    var userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User);
    //UserNamesToList = GetUserNamesList();
    /*
    var NamesToListQ = userAccesses.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                               {
                                                    Value = x.User.Id,
                                                    Text = x.User.Name
                                               });

    var NamesToList = new SelectList(NamesToListQ, "Value", "Text");
    */


    if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User);


        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Date":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User).OrderBy(s => s.Access);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User).OrderByDescending(s => s.Access);
                break;
            case "Email_desc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User).OrderByDescending(s => s.User.Email);
                break;
            case "Email_asc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User).OrderBy(s => s.User.Email);
                break;
            case "ID_desc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User).OrderByDescending(s => s.UserAcessID);
                break;
            case "ID_asc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User).OrderBy(s => s.UserAcessID);
                break;
            case "Name_asc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User).OrderBy(s => s.User.Name);
                break;
            case "Name_desc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User).OrderBy(s => s.User.Name);
                break;
            default:
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User).OrderBy(s => s.UserAcessID);
                break;
        }


        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User)
                            .Where(s => s.User.Email.Contains(searchString) || s.User.Id.Contains(searchString));

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "Date":
                    userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User)
                            .Where(s => s.User.Email.Contains(searchString) || s.User.Id.Contains(searchString))
                            .OrderBy(s => s.Access);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User)
                            .Where(s => s.User.Email.Contains(searchString) || s.User.Id.Contains(searchString))
                            .OrderByDescending(s => s.Access);
                    break;
                case "Email_desc":
                    userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User)
                            .Where(s => s.User.Email.Contains(searchString) || s.User.Id.Contains(searchString))
                            .OrderByDescending(s => s.User.Email);
                    break;
                case "Email_asc":
                    userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User)
                            .Where(s => s.User.Email.Contains(searchString) || s.User.Id.Contains(searchString))
                            .OrderBy(s => s.User.Email);
                    break;
                case "ID_desc":
                    userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User)
                            .Where(s => s.User.Email.Contains(searchString) || s.User.Id.Contains(searchString))
                            .OrderByDescending(s => s.UserAcessID);
                    break;
                case "ID_asc":
                    userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User)
                            .Where(s => s.User.Email.Contains(searchString) || s.User.Id.Contains(searchString))
                            .OrderBy(s => s.UserAcessID);
                    break;
                case "Name_asc":
                    userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User)
                            .Where(s => s.User.Email.Contains(searchString) || s.User.Id.Contains(searchString))
                            .OrderBy(s => s.User.Name);
                    break;
                case "Name_desc":
                    userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User)
                            .Where(s => s.User.Email.Contains(searchString) || s.User.Id.Contains(searchString))
                            .OrderByDescending(s => s.User.Name);
                    break;
                default:
                    userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User)
                            .Where(s => s.User.Email.Contains(searchString) || s.User.Id.Contains(searchString))
                            .OrderBy(s => s.Access);
                    break;
            }

        }

    }
    else
    {
        var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Where(u => u.UserID == id).Include(i => i.User).Where(u => u.UserID == id);


        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Date":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .Include(i => i.User)
                                              .Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .OrderBy(s => s.Access);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .Include(i => i.User)
                                              .Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .OrderByDescending(s => s.Access);
                break;
            case "Email_desc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .Include(i => i.User)
                                              .Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .OrderByDescending(s => s.User.Email);
                break;
            case "Email_asc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .Include(i => i.User)
                                              .Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .OrderBy(s => s.User.Email);
                break;
            case "ID_desc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .Include(i => i.User)
                                              .Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .OrderByDescending(s => s.UserAcessID);
                break;
            case "ID_asc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .Include(i => i.User)
                                              .Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .OrderBy(s => s.UserAcessID);
                break;
            case "Name_asc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .Include(i => i.User)
                                              .Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .OrderBy(s => s.User.Name);
                break;
            case "Name_desc":
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .Include(i => i.User)
                                              .Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .OrderBy(s => s.User.Name);
                break;
            default:
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .Include(i => i.User)
                                              .Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                                              .OrderBy(s => s.Access);
                break;
        }

    }


    return View(userAccesses.ToList());

}
```

As you can see, in the commented lines i do a query that return a list with user names.

**My problem is: How I access this list on que view?**

I put this on my view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedUserRoleId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedUserRoleId, Model.UserRoles)
```

but I can't use "Model.something".

TiA!

Comment: Instead of using `userAccesses.ToList()` as your model, you need to create a model class in the `Models` directory that has all the properties your view needs.

Comment: @PaulAbbott but the list is on my UserAccess class.
[See here](https://gyazo.com/a3f6986c4d44aa8dd3e8f24df5165711)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a model class in the `Models` directory with the properties the view needs:

```
public class MyModelOfSomething
{
    public IEnumerable<UserAccess> UserAccesses { get; set; }

    public SelectList NamesToList { get; set; }
}
```

Populate that model in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string sortOrder)
{
    var model = new MyModelOfSomething();

    ...

    model.NamesToList = new SelectList(NamesToListQ, "Value", "Text");

    ...

    model.UserAccesses = userAccesses.ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

Now you can access both using `@Model.NamesToList` and `@Model.UserAccesses` in the view.

Comment: cal you tell mt another thing? I want to have on my dropdown "All", but obviously it isn't on my list, how I do that?