# Output ICollection dropdownlist method corresponding to collection form query

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I have 2 models (Movies and Actors)

I already can retrieve a list of Movie that contains selected Actors. And I can output all of it via Html.DisplayNameFor. But I wanna use DDL to output Icollection Actors instead of cycle with subitem in @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Actors).  So I need dropdownlist corresponded toSelectedList Actor. default output is all/ And if I select specific Movie param such Genre or Budget than DDL with Actors should correspond to this.

```
public class Movie
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string  Date { get; set; }
    public int Budget { get; set; }
    public string  Genre { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}

public class Actor
{  
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

I realize output with

```
   <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
    </th>........................

    <th>.........................
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Actors)
    </th>...............
```

With `Actors` collection I need another form for every row of my output. Because every film can have many actors.
If Actors have to much columns how can I hide it? Or output some quantity with ability to expand it? 
I choose to add them to DropDownList.
Maybe some new AJAX form or asp.net element would be good alternative.

Hence I have MovieController:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchActor))
{             
    Movie = Movie.Where(c => c.Actors.Any(i => i.Name.Contains(SearchActor)));
}

return View(Movie.ToList());
```

It returns a movie. How can I retrieve `Actors.Name` (string) from `Movie` corresponding to Actor ICollection?

I would add this string to DDL.

Comment: I dont quite understand the question? Do you want the first Actors name or a List of actors by movie? as you say you need a string

Comment: I already can retrieve a list of Movie that contains selected Actors. And I can output all of it via Html.DisplayNameFor. But I wanna use DDL to output Icollection Actors instead of cycle with subitem in @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Actors).  So I need dropdownlist corresponded toSelectedList Actor. default output is all/ And if I select specific Movie param such Genre or Budget than DDL with Actors should correspond to this. Thanks! A try to be more clear. I edit my question.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to show a drop-down list?

Comment: Output drop-down list with dynamically changing Actors Collection depending on Movie I select,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var actors = Movie.Where(c => c.Actors.Any(i => i.Name.Contains(SearchActor))).SelectMany(i => i.Actors);
```

Comment: I made this earlier. But how can I add it to Dropdownlist? var AllActors = Movie.Where(c => c.Actors.Any(i => i.Name.Contains(SearchActor))).SelectMany(u => u.Actors);
            var ActorLst = new List<string>();
            ActorLst.AddRange(AllActors.Distinct()); And I get conversion Error

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382311/populating-a-razor-dropdownlist-from-a-listobject-in-mvc @ifooi

Comment: OK, Thanks. I change list of string to list of Actor. And I would read.

Comment: Movie.Where(c => c.Actors.Any(i => i.Name.Contains(SearchActor))).SelectMany(i => i.Actors).Select(i => new { i.Name}) @ifooi

Comment: var AllActors = Movie.Where(c => c.Actors.Any(i => i.Name.Contains(SearchActor))).SelectMany(i => i.Actors).Select(i => new { i.Name });
            var ActorLst = new List<string>();
            ActorLst.AddRange(AllActors.Distinct()); cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: string Name>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' Sorry men. And Thabks.

Comment: Just chage **new { i.Name}** to **i.Name** @ifooi

Comment: Yes, it works correctly and halfway done but I need to think more total. With var AllActors = Movie.Where(c => c.Actors.Any(i => i.Name.Contains(SearchActor))).SelectMany(i => i.Actors).Select(i => i.Name); I can output actors  for only selected actors. That good but when I select movie that construction outputs all actors despite not all of them  exists in Movie, Logically I think I need add more Contains to var.

Comment: And add some logical conditions.