# Populating razor object using IEnumerable returns error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in my model:

```
   public class ProjectViewModel
   {
     [Display(Name = "Project Status")]
     public int SelectedStatusId { get; set; }
     public SelectList StatusList { get; set; }
   }
```

Following is the class (which is inside the Repository Folder) that retrieves set of status from database:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LoadStatus()
    {
        using (ProjectEntities proj = new ProjectEntities())
        {
            var statList = proj.ProjectStatus.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.ProjStatusID.ToString(),
                Text = x.ProjStatusCode
            });
            return new SelectList(statList, "Value", "Text");
        }

    }
```

Following is my code on Controller:

```
public class ProjectMasterController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult LoadProjectStatus()
    {
        ProjectDataManager pm = new ProjectDataManager();
        var model = new ProjectViewModel();

        model.StatusList = new SelectList(pm.LoadStatus(), "ProjStatusID",   "ProjStatusCode");

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And, finally the View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedStatusId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedStatusId, Model.StatusList,"Select Status")
```

I have referred the [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382311/populating-a-razor-dropdownlist-from-a-listobject-in-mvc) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142961/mvc3-dropdownlistfor-a-simple-example) on StackOverflow. But I am getting an error,

> The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedStatusId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

I am not sure where i am going wrong

Comment: In addition to the dupe, change your property to `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusList { get; set; }` - You create one `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the `LoadStatus` method. Then you create another identical one from it using `return new SelectList(statList, "Value", "Text");`. Then you create a 3rd identical one in the `LoadProjectStatus()` by using `model.StatusList = new SelectList(..)` again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this line.

```
 model.StatusList = new SelectList(pm.LoadStatus(), "ProjStatusID",   "ProjStatusCode");
```

But your pm.LoadStatus returns a a list of `SelectListItem`. Each item in the list will have `Value` property and `Text` property, There will not be a `ProjeStatusID` and `ProjStatusCode` property. That line is going to crash!

This should solve that problem.

```
 model.StatusList = new SelectList(pm.LoadStatus(), "Value",   "Text");
```

or even

```
vm.StatusList = pm.LoadStatus() as SelectList;
```

Comment: Thank you.It worked out.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code in controller to below
model.StatusList = pm.LoadStatus()