# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'x'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu, view

In my view i have a problem and my dropdownlist fails and doesn't work don't know why

```
@model DigikalaHR.View_Model.Entitys.Member
 .
 .
 .
 .
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeamId, "TeamId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">                
            @Html.DropDownList("TeamId",null,htmlAttributes: new {@clas="form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeamId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

in this code this is the error that i get

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'TeamId'.'

if i change the code to this one

```
@Html.DropDownList("TeamId",model=>model.TeamId,htmlAttributes: new {@clas="form-control" })
```

this is the error that i receive

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IEnumerable' because it is not a delegate type

also this is my Create method in my controller

```
  #region [- Create() -]

    #region [- Get -]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    #endregion

    #region [- Post -]
    // POST: Member/Create
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string _fName, string _lName, string _describtion, string _pic, int _teamId, int _positionId)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            Ref_Member = new View_Model.Buisiness.Member();
            //Ref_Member.CreateMember();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

and this is my View model that i passed into my view

```
  #region [- Id -]
    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    [DisplayName("شماره")]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    #endregion

    #region [- FName -]
    [DisplayName("نام")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName  = "StringLength")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region [- LName -]
    [DisplayName("نام خانوادگی ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLength")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region [- Describtion -]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [DisplayName("توضیحات")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region [- Pic -]
    [DisplayName("عکس")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings =false,ErrorMessageResourceType =typeof(Resources.Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string Pic { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region [- TeamId -]
    [DisplayName("شماره تیم")]
    public Nullable<int> TeamId { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region [- PositionId -]
    [DisplayName("شماره سرپرست")]
    public int PositionId { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region [- Departments -]
    [DisplayName("دپارتمان")]
    public ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; } 
    #endregion

    public  Position Position { get; set; }
    public  Team Team { get; set; }

    public  ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it really supposed to be `@clas=`, and not `@class = `?

Comment: @RobertHarvey i fixed it but still i get the same error

Comment: Well, based on the error message you're receiving: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IEnumerable' because it is not a delegate type`, it appears that your `@Html.DropDownList` call expects a *collection* in that parameter, but you are providing a single value instead.

Comment: And if you look at the [documentation for the method overload you're calling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537935(v=vs.111).aspx), I think you'll find that it confirms what the error message is already telling you: it expects an `IEnumerable`, but you're providing it with a single item.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but it's a form it must be  simple and single not a Collection

Comment: You need a list of things in your dropdown, not a single item.  If you only have a single item to choose from, then you don't need a dropdown.

Comment: how can i show a collection of stuff in `dropdownlist`

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18382610

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on the error message you're receiving: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IEnumerable' because it is not a delegate type`, it appears that your `@Html.DropDownList` call expects a *collection* in that parameter, but you are providing a single value instead.

And if you look at the [documentation for the method overload you're calling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537935(v=vs.111).aspx), I think you'll find that it confirms what the error message is already telling you: it expects an `IEnumerable`, but you're providing it with a single item.

[This article](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor) provides some decent code samples.  Here is an example:

```
@Html.DropDownList("StudentGender", 
                    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))),
                    "Select Gender",
                    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Notice the use of `Enum.GetValues`, which produces an IEnumerable.

To bind it to a field in your form, you need something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StudentGender, 
                    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))), 
                    "Select Gender")
```

**Further Reading**
[Populating a razor dropdownlist from a List in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18382610)

Comment: thank's a lot but what should  use instead of `Gender`

Comment: That would depend on what your Model looks like.

Comment: i'll edit my question

Comment: It doesn't appear that you have a suitable list in your model that you can use to populate the dropdown.

Comment: so i should fill a list and then pass it instead of `Gender`

Comment: Exactly .......