# EF Core .ToList() Query Returning "{Namespace.Models.Model}" Instead of Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I have a model called `Situation` and I'm simply getting all of them so I can list them in a dropdown box in a view. Here's my query:

```
var situations = _context.Situations.ToList();
```

Dropdown box:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SituationID", null, "Pick One: ", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The weird part is that each of the elements in the returned set are my `Namespace.Models.Situation` instead of the values at the top level.

My other query to return users (`public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser`) returns their email addresses for [0], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYvxz.png)... then the properties below them. Here are screenshots at a break point:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Other than the fact I still have very little understanding about how to use the @Html.DropDownList HtmlHelper (more on that in other questions), I can't figure out what's different between the two. There are no errors clearly, but I have no idea where to go from here. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18382610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to transform your list of `Situation` items into a list of `SelectListItem`. It should be something like:

```
ViewBag.Situations = _context.Situations
    .Select(situation => new SelectListItem { Text = situation.XXX, Value = situation.YYY })
    .ToList();
```

And then in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SituationID", ViewBag.Situations, "Pick One: ", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Where `XXX` and `YYY` are the properties you want to use as the display text of the item and the ID of the item (respectively).

You can also take a look at [Using the DropDownList Helper with ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc) for a complete example.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Itay, but I'm not sure what the `DropDownList` code should look like. Any tips? I'm working my way through that MS guide too :)

Comment: That worked to populate the list items and values, now I just have to figure out why the `SituationID` and `ApplicationUserId` fields didn't update in the database. That's for another time. :)

Answer (score 3):

this is not Ef Problem. this is your fault in rendering DropDownList.
You must change your data schema to a proper data structure such as Dictionary or An Value-Text class (SelectList). and then Bind it to your DropDown.

this is code example for your problem:

```
ViewBag.SituationList = _context.Situations.Select( x=> new SelectListItem{Value= x.Id, , Text= x.SituationName}).ToList();
```

and then Bind it to your Dropdown using this code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.label, (SelectList)ViewBag.SituationList)
```

Comment: 3 Errors: 1) "Select list doesn't contain a definition for 'Value'", 2) 1) "Select list doesn't contain a definition for 'Text'", 3) 'SelectList' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Comment: yes, you are right it was my typo... I edit my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a collection of objects, like Situation objects, that have many properties like ExitURL and Caption, and you tell some list helper to use the collection as a source of data for the list, it cannot know which property you wanted to pick as the display text. As a result it will just call ToString on each object and use what is returned as the display text. In its default implementation, ToString returns a representation of the type of the object - this is what you're seeing

You thus have a choice;

- persist in your current style and override ToString so it returns text for your display,
- reduce the collection of Situation objects to a collection of strings (for each Situation, make a string representing it from whichever properties you like) and use that string collection as your list driver, or
- transform the collection into a SelectListItem collection so that you give the list helper access to a collection of objects it knows how to work with - you can thus direct it as to which Situation property you want to use for various attributes of the resulting HTML (e.g. Use the ExitUrl as the HTML control's Value, and the Caption as the display text). Where you do this transform probably depends on how you need to reuse your data