# Where to load dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

Where to load dropdown list of country list in MVC Asp.net? Should we populate the dropdown in controller or in model itself? Any example.

Comment: You might wanna search SO first. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382311/populating-a-razor-dropdownlist-from-a-listobject-in-mvc

Comment: I would always suggest to populate the dropdown in the controller

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the list to view model from controller action and populate it in the razor view.you can find more at the following link http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor

Answer (score 0):

It depends, for example if you store countries in your database, its probably better to build the SelectList in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var countries = db.Countries.ToList();      // get your countries
    var model = new CountryViewModel();
    model.Countries = new SelectList(countries,"Id","Name");
    return View(model);
}
```

I guess your `CountryViewModel` can look like this:

```
public class CountryViewModel{
   public SelectList Countries {get;set;}
   public int CountryId {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your view you can show the DropDown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, Model.Countries, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If it is a static list you can populate it in the model itself:

```
public class CountryViewModel{
   public SelectList Countries {get;set;}
   public int CountryId {get;set;}

   public CountryViewModel{
       Countries = new SelectList(GetCountriesFormSomeGlobalPlace(),"Id","Name");
   }
}
```

Generally, do not use your code first models in your views (if you are using code first that is), but rather use `ViewModel` `POCOs`.