# How Read a selected text from the drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to save the user selected text to the db.I tried 3 different ways but all of them return null for the selected
value.  value1 or value2 or value3 returns null. What I am doing to wrong here ?

```
   <div id="reasonsList" style="display: none">
    @foreach (var reason in Model.CorrectionReasonsList)
    {
        <option>@(reason)</option>
    }
</div>
var value = '<option selected="selected" value="' + sData + '">' + sData + '</option>';

var reasonsSelect = '<select id="correction_reason_dropdown" ' +
         'multiple ' +
         'style="min-width:115px" ' +
         'data-select-options={"searchField":"false","noValueText":"Select One"))"} ' +
         'class="select multiple-as-single compact correction-reason" ' +
          '>';                

          reasonsSelect += value + $("#reasonsList").html();
           reasonsSelect += "</select>";
            $(nTd).html(reasonsSelect);


var value1 = $('#reasonsList:selected').val();
var value2 = $('#reasonsList:selected').find('option:selected').text();
var value3 = $('#reasonsList:selected').text();
```

Comment: Did you check [Get selected text from a drop-down list (select box) using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-a-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery)

Comment: `#reasonsList` is a `<div>`, not a `<select>` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get selected text from drop down not the `div`. Below code should do:

`$("#correction_reason_dropdown:selected").text();`

Comment: After looking closely at the code, it doesn't look right to nest the the option tag inside the div and then take its values to populate the drop down. Why not to create a select list items and use the @Html.DropDownListFor function like in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727386/dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-with-razor

Comment: Ramin, Thank you for looking through my code. It is a really complicated view . I  only posted bare minim above.  @Html.dropdown  was my first choice too but it did not work. Then I tried to solve it with the help of  javascript and jQuery. I guess this does not work either.

Comment: I changed the reasons select by adding the index of the row and it worked : 
               var reasonsSelect = '<select id="correction_reason_dropdown' +     iRow + '" ' +
 var v1 = $("#correction_reason_dropdown" + index + " option:selected").text();