# I want to get list of countries from database and bind it to dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my code gives me error while add `countrylist` to `listofcountries`

ERROR

> system.collection.generic.list is not assignable to parameter type
>   system.web.mvc.selectListitem

CODE

```
public List<SelectListItem> Getallcountries()
{
    var listofcountries = new List<SelectListItem>();
    using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var countrylist = db.Countries.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.CountryName,
            Value = Convert.ToString(x.ID)
        });

       listofcountries.Add(countrylist);
    }
    return listofcountries;
}
```

Comment: `List<SelectListItem>` and `selectListitem` are different types.

Comment: How to solve it i want to return list of countries

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727386/dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-with-razor

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh, That link has nothing to do with OP's issue.

Comment: try listofcountries.AddRange(countrylist);

Comment: Remove `listofcountries.Add(countrylist);` and change it to `return countrylist.ToList();` (you query is already generating a collection of `SelectListItem`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the list generated by code directly. No need to add it to another list

```
public List<SelectListItem> Getallcountries()
{

    using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var countrylist = db.Countries.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.CountryName,
            Value = Convert.ToString(x.ID)
        });

       return  countrylist.ToList();
    }

}
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke Removed the statement

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 using(var db=new dbContect()
  {
      var count=db.Countries.Where(x=>x.IsActive==true).Select(a=>new SelectListItem{
    Text=a.CountyName,
    Value=SqlFunctions.StringConvert(a.ID)
}).ToList();
```

return count;
      }