# ASP.NET MVC DropDownList with constant content in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new in ASP.NET MVC, please excuse me if my question is too simple. I would like to create an ASP.NET MVC DropDownList with constant content, only with 4 items:"Patient list","Benchmarking","Center Specific","ECMO Run". What is the simplest method to do that in razor? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727386/dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-with-razor

Comment: thank you, I have found corresponding answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view :

```
@{
   List<SelectListItem> listItems= new List<SelectListItem>();
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "Patient list", Value = "Patient list"});
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "Benchmarking", Value = "Benchmarking"});
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "Center Specific",Value = "Center Specific"});
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "ECMO Run",Value = "ECMO Run"});
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MySelectedItem, listItems, "-- Select --")
```

in your controller I assume you have a model object which has a property called MySelectedItem. So in controller the action method code would be like this :

```
public ActionResult MyAction(...)
{
   ...
   model.MySelectedItem="Benchmarking";// just as example
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Could you please explain how to implement an event like "SelectedIndexChange" in the DropDownList?

Comment: You're welcome. you can simply give an Id to your control with :  
`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MySelectedItem, listItems, "-- Select --", new {@id='myDropdown'})` and add this javascript to your view `$('select#myDropdown').change(function() {/* your javascript code */});` and throw that javascript code you can do whatever you want. BTW I assumed you're using JQuery.