# MVC DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, viewmodel, html.dropdownlistfor, dropdownlistfor

I am new using MVC approach. How to using the DropDownListfor in the MVC? I need get the list from my master table and show the option into the Business Premise in the Business Profile object.
This is my ViewModel

```
 public class SMEAppViewModel 

{        
    public WP2PBusinessProfile BuisinessProfile  { get; set; }        
    public IEnumerable<WP2PMasterDropDownList> MasterList { get; set; }       

}
```

In my controller, I already initialize the MasterList to the List

```
 var _MasterList = _context.WP2PMasterDropDownList.ToList();
```

And in my view, I able to display all the option in the List by using the following code

```
 @foreach (var karim in Model.MasterList.Where(c => c.Variable == "BusinessPremise"))
                    {

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => karim.Value) <br>                            

                    }
```

However, I using the following dropdownlistfor in my view, but my DropDownlistfor is not able to show my drop down option in my view.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BuisinessProfile.BusinessPremise, new SelectList(Model.MasterList, "Id", "Value"), "Select value")
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BuisinessProfile.BusinessPremise, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

would anyone tell me any wrong in my code?

Thanks

Comment: what does *but my DropDownlistfor is not able to show my drop down option in my view* mean?

Comment: Your select list of options looks wrong. It should be a `List<T>` of `SelectListItem` like this question:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DropDownList in MVC 4 with Razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727386/dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-with-razor)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this in your view**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Entity, new Project.Models.My_Class().My_Method, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

You cant get data from your DropDownListFor.

In the My_Method ,  You can use SelectList

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display text options in dropdown then try to use list of 'selectlistitem' and then fill out this list with foreach loop like

```
List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var temp in yourlist)
{
   ls.Add(new SelectListItem() 
   { Text = temp.textfield, Value = Convert.ToString(temp.valuefield) });
}
```

after this add this list to your view field (MasterList for your case but change type to `List<SelectListItem>`) this will display the dropdown list and to get selected value you can use javascript and jquery with ajax call for further process.

```
var dropdownvalue = $("#AccountGroupID option:selected").val();
var dropdowntext = $("#AccountGroupID option:selected").text();
```

this will give you value and text for selected item.

In view to display dropdownlist you can try it like this.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BuisinessProfile, new SelectList(Model.MasterList, "Value", "Text"), "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "dropdown"})
```