# How do I list the int datatype?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller, integer, boolean

I have such a column in my database;

public int marker_type { get; set; }

My question is how can I use dropdownlistfor to show this column as orange if 0 is selected if apple is 1 selected. I tried to use "enum" but failed.

[image]

In this image, you see the database where the column is located and the location of the "enum" folder.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVC DropDownListFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297883/mvc-dropdownlistfor)

Answer (score 0):

could you explain better what you want? if you want your list to only work when your variable value is 1 you can try this.

Create a string **startData**

```
if(orange=0){    
var listA= from d in YourDB
       select ;
       var listB = listA.Distinct();
       ViewBag.startData = new SelectList(listB);
}
else{
 return View();
}
```

if you could show the database and the field you want to load would be a help