# How to create Combo box field using razor code in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, html-helper

I have a requirement to create a Combo box field, which has a dropdown list and also we can enter text in it. I google it and found **datalist** tag that is used in the **input** element to display the dropdown list.

Now, my question is, is there any other way to create combo box field?
or
Can we create combo box using HTML Helpers?

Thanks.

Comment: There are javascript library alternatives

Comment: You probably don't want to do it on razor as there are far better options out there using Html/Javascript libraries, but here is one solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17727558/1324022